# How do i get, for example : getName() of the desired position inside an ArrayList <MyClass>?

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

I'm working with basic collections right now and I'm having troubles with they `ArrayList` methods like `.get(int)` because that would return the entire object, in my case Name,Age,Phone,Salary,...etc but I just want to get the name of the object in the position desired.

The list is already loaded and the methods done, and I`m currently with this :

```
System.out.println("Desired Position?");
pos = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
for(Employee i : list)
{
     if(list.indexOf(i)==pos)  // <- Was out of ideas here
     {
         System.out.println(i.getName());
     }       
}
```

So... the thing is: I enter the position and that for-each loop is supposed to check through the list, if the index of the list matches with the one I want, it prints the name.

Thank you, and sorry for my barely comprehensible English

Comment: try `list.get(pos).getName()`. ArrayLists offer fast by-index lookup.

Comment: My God...it was that easy? now i feel bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the index of a List directly by using the `get(int)` method. It is zero-based, so remember to start from zero, not from one.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        list.add(new Employee("Alex"));
        list.add(new Employee("John"));
        list.add(new Employee("Mary"));

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Desired Position between 0 and 2?");
        int pos = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println(list.get(pos).getName());
    }
}

class Employee
{
    private String name;

    Employee(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply try:

```
System.out.println("Desired Position?");
pos = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
if(pos > 0 && pos < list.size()) {
    System.out.println(list.get(pos).getName());
}
```

Comment: Now that i got the list.get(pos).getName() and knowing that you just have to input the position in the .get(), isnt it unnecessary to use any kind of conditional or loop? or is it better to do so?

Comment: No loop necessary unless you want to achieve something else. Ask a new question if you need a new answer :)